# Laptop restarts because of running chrome on android studio emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, emulation, android-virtual-device

Whenever i run google chrome on the android studio emulator (Pixel 8 Pro API VanillaIceCream) then trying to search of pressing on specific website my laptop restart from itself and it gives me a blue screen for a sec..... my laptop specs is I9 11th GEN. , RTX 3060 and 16 GB RAM so i don't think that it's because of my hardware.
Also i noticed that the emulator consume a lot from the CPU whenever i run chrome and open a website it consume like 90% or 100%

Anyone know a solution? i use Android Studio Iguana 2023.2.1 btw

I tried a multiple emulators versions like Pixel 7 and 6 and i tried to uninstall android studio and install it again but the same happened.